# populate drop-down list with database using ajax in laravel

Tags: html, ajax, database, laravel, phpmyadmin

i'm trying to fetch data from the database in dropdown list but it is not showing ,i have also watch several tutorials but things are not working as expected

> Controller :

```
 public function cost(Request $request){
            $lab_data = \DB::table('lab_category')->select('category_name')->get();
              //return $lab_data;
        return view('medicinecost')->with('lab_category',$lab_data);
          }
```

> Route :

```
Route::get('labdetails','Test@cost');
Route::get('labprice',function (){
    return view('pages/medicinecost');
});
```

> medicinecost.blade.php

```
<div class="form-group">
    <select name="labCat" id="lab" class="form-control input-lg dynamic" data-dependent="labSubCat">
    <option value="{{$lab_data}}">Select Lab Category</option>
        @foreach($lab_data as $lb)
            <option value="{{$lb->lab_category_id}}">{{$lb->category_name}}</option>
        @endforeach
    </select>
</div>
```

> I am getting this error

```
ErrorException in 1180188cd7aaaebdb54a13bbf08bc2d80ab30f15.php line 15:
Undefined variable: lab_data (View: C:\xampp72\htdocs\hospital\resources\views\pages\medicinecost.blade.php)
```

Comment: show your `medicinecost` file

Comment: can you provide the code of your view where you are trying to populate dropdown

Comment: use `lab_category` instead of `lab_data` in `foreach loop`

Comment: i have tried it @BhargavChudasama but giving me the same error.

Comment: what route you are getting error

Comment: which error comes?

Comment: Can you tell why you are using \DB::table() in your controller? Is it because of the path difference?

Comment: you'll surely get an error/bug if the problem (here) is solved because you select only `category_name` and you try to use `lab_category_id` also. Change your select conditions

Answer (score 3, accepted):

use this

```
<div class="form-group">
    <select name="labCat" id="lab" class="form-control input-lg dynamic" data-dependent="labSubCat">
    <option value="">Select Lab Category</option>
        @if(isset($lab_category))
        @foreach($lab_category as $lb)
            <option value="{{$lb->lab_category_id}}">{{$lb->category_name}}</option>
        @endforeach
        @endif
    </select>
</div>


Route::get('labprice',function (){
    $lab_data = \DB::table('lab_category')->select('category_name')->get();
          //return $lab_data;
    return view('pages/medicinecost')->with('lab_category',$lab_data);
});
```

Comment: i have used this your code @Shaielndra Gupta ,undefined variable solved but list is not coming

Comment: @Prathamesh as I previously said you have to clarify on which route you are getting the error

Comment: On Route labprice i'm getting an error,your code solves 80% problem,i'm almost there

Comment: on that route, you are directly returning the view so how that variable can be accessed

Comment: i have used this route  but it gives an error View [medicinecost] not found.

Comment: It gives the error because your page `page/medicinecost` is not your blade name, it looks like your `route`. Question: is your blade `medicinecost` is inside the folder `page` or not, if no then remove `pages.medicinecost` and use `medicinecost`

Answer (score 2):

In Controller you need to select lab_category_id as well :

```
$lab_data = \DB::table('lab_category')->select('lab_category_id','category_name')->get();
```

Also fix the way you pass params, And no need to pass lab_category :

```
return view('medicinecost')->with('lab_data');
```

In view make its default value like 0 or empty:

```
<option value="0">Select Lab Category</option>
```

Answer (score 2):

try this code

**controller**

```
 return view('medicinecost',['lab_category'=>$lab_data]);
```

**medicinecost.blade.php**

```
<div class="form-group">
    <select name="labCat" id="lab" class="form-control input-lg dynamic" data-dependent="labSubCat">
    <option value="">Select Lab Category</option>
        @foreach($lab_category as $lb)
            <option value="{{$lb->lab_category_id}}">{{$lb->category_name}}</option>
        @endforeach
    </select>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Error is here

```
<option value="{{$lab_data}}">Select Lab Category</option>
```

and also here

```
@foreach($lab_data as $lb)
```

You're defining `$lab_data` in the controller, but passed with the variable of `lab_category` in the view

So, used `@foreach($lab_category as $lb)` as they mentioned before in the answer and remove `{{ $lab_data }}` in the `option-value`

Comment: yes tried the same but still data is not populating in the dropdown

Comment: yes man i have used dd(); for that variable and it is coming in JSON format

Comment: json format? can you quickly change your `return view` like this `return::view('medicinecost', ['lab_category' => $lab_data ]);` but not sure whether it will solve your problem or not

Answer (score 1):

You may try this.

**Your Controller**

```
public function cost(Request $request){
            $lab_category = \DB::table('lab_category')->select('category_name','lab_category_id')->get();
        return view('medicinecost', compact('lab_category'));
          }
```

**Your View**

```
<div class="form-group">
    <select name="labCat" id="lab" class="form-control input-lg dynamic" data-dependent="labSubCat">
    <option value="">Select Lab Category</option>
        @foreach($lab_category as $lb)
            <option value="{{$lb->lab_category_id}}">{{$lb->category_name}}</option>
        @endforeach
    </select>
</div>
```